# Object become null when converted to json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Here is the problem, when I send my object to server using retrofit I got it null. I'm doing this to create the json object:

```
HashMap<String, UserModel> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("user", user);
```

But, when the json arrives in the server I got something like this:

```
{"user":null}
```

Then I printed ny json file with this line:

```
Log.d("TAG", new JSONObject(map).toString());
```

And I saw the same null object.

So, **here is my question, Why is this happening? And how can I fix that?**

Here goes some information about my project:

```
Retrofit version: 2.0.0
Retrofit serializer: jackson version 2.0.0
using also jackson to convert JodaTime version 2.4.0
```

here goes how I get retrofit instance:

```
public T buildServiceInstance(Class<T> clazz){
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_HOST)
                                     .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                                     .build().create(clazz);
    }
```

I call that method here:

```
public static final IUserApi serviceInstance = new ApiBuildRequester<IUserApi>()
                                                                .buildServiceInstance(IUserApi.class);
```

Method declaration on interface IUserApi:

```
@POST("User.svc/Save")
Call<ResponseSaveUserApiModel> save(@Body HashMap<String, UserModel> map);
```

And at last, but I guess, not less important:

```
public class UserModel implements Parcelable {


    private String idUser;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String safePassword;
    private String salt;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String facebookProfilePictureUrl;
    private String facebookUserId;

    public UserModel() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(String idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSafePassword() {
        return safePassword;
    }

    public void setSafePassword(String safePassword) {
        this.safePassword = safePassword;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getFacebookProfilePictureUrl() {
        return facebookProfilePictureUrl;
    }

    public void setFacebookProfilePictureUrl(String facebookProfilePictureUrl) {
        this.facebookProfilePictureUrl = facebookProfilePictureUrl;
    }

    public String getFacebookUserId() {
        return facebookUserId;
    }

    public void setFacebookUserId(String facebookUserId) {
        this.facebookUserId = facebookUserId;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public UserModel(Parcel in) { // Deve estar na mesma ordem do "writeToParcel"
        setIdUser(in.readString());
        setName(in.readString());
        setEmail(in.readString());
        setSafePassword(in.readString());
        setPhoneNumber(in.readString());
        setFacebookProfilePictureUrl(in.readString());
        setFacebookUserId(in.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) { //Deve estar na mesma ordem do construtor que recebe parcel
        dest.writeString(idUser);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeString(safePassword);
        dest.writeString(phoneNumber);
        dest.writeString(facebookProfilePictureUrl);
        dest.writeString(facebookUserId);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UserModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UserModel>(){
        @Override
        public UserModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new UserModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public UserModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UserModel[size];
        }
    };

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }
}
```

Debug screen:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your user object is not null at the serialisation time?

Comment: @MikhailChibel yes, I've debugged, check the screenshot

Comment: org.json (JSONObject) has no mapper API. It cannot translate your pojo to json. Read wrap documentation!

Comment: Yeah, you may want to use Jackson deserialization to check your map instead of `new JSONObject(map).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

@Selvin and @cricket_007 You are the best!

I got this using your hint that my printing was wrong, and I found the solution.
I have two types of users in my app, facebook users or native users, two forms, but just one object, and here was the problem, **when I sent facebook objects (complete) it worked fine, but when I tried to send native users, with some null properties, it crashed my serialization.**

So I had to check every property before send it, it's just a workaround, but for now it's enough, thank you a lot folks!